# Python Wierd Loop Output FTP

Tags: python, for-loop, ftp

Using a function block list to list FTP directory.

```
def list_directory():
        try:
            ftp = ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")
            ftp.login(username, password)
            files = []
            files = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
           if str(resp) == "550 No files or directory found":
                print "No files in this directory"
           else:
                raise

        for x in files:
            print files

list_directory()
```

---

This is the output.

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 ftpclient1 ftpclient1     4096 Jun 25 21:14 directory1
drwxr-xr-x   2 ftpclient1 ftpclient1     4096 Jun 25 21:18 directory2
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
226 Transfer complete
```

What am I doing wrong that cause this "226 Transfer complete" multiple times and how is it corrected?

When I try to correct it

```
def list_directory():
        try:
            ftp = ftplib.FTP("192.168.189.130")
            ftp.login(username, password)
            files = []
            files = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
           if str(resp) == "550 No files or directory found":
                print "No files in this directory"
           else:
                raise

        for x in files:
            print x

list_directory()
```

Changing the print variable from `print files` to `print x` i get this.

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 ftpclient1 ftpclient1     4096 Jun 25 21:14 directory1
drwxr-xr-x   2 ftpclient1 ftpclient1     4096 Jun 25 21:18 directory2
2
2
6

T
r
a
n
s
f
e
r

c
o
m
p
l
e
t
e
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Files is a string. Print only files variable and you should see 226 transfer complete. Right now you are iterating through each character present in that string .

Answer (score 0):

Thank You So Much!

Made changes to the function and getting expected output now :-)

Here are changes:

```
                return True
           return False
#       else:
#               raise

#       for x in files:
        print files
```

And based on "purrogrammer" says, it make sense. Commented out the "else" , the "raise" and the "for x in files"(loop). Instead using the "return" True or False. Now getting output desired.

Thanks!
:-)